# Count user within <15 min and 15-to 30 min sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

table name customer visit

```
CustomerId, phoneMacAddress,  CreateDatetime 
1002        1b:66:41:11:26:16  2017-07-17 07:33:31.300
1003        cb:45:85:25:2:0    2017-07-17 07:05:21.200
1004        3o:09:ab:1c:5:ab   2017-07-17 10:03:01.400
1002        1b:66:41:11:26:16  2017-07-17 08:12:03.543
1002        1b:66:41:11:26:16  2017-07-17 08:12:03.543
1002        1b:66:41:11:26:16  2017-07-17 08:09:27.527
```

How to get data this format:

```
<15min      15-30min      >30min
1           4             0
```

Comment: Describe how to count? Your sample data has 3 different users, but still you want 4 as count (for 15-30 minutes.)

Comment: i need query for sql server

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE for SQL SERVER

```
#Last 15 mins
SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM customer_visit WHERE CreateDatetime >= DateADD(mi, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and CreateDatetime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

#Between 15 to 30 min
SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM customer_visit WHERE CreateDatetime >= DateADD(mi, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and CreateDatetime <= DateADD(mi, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

In MySQL you can use this query and adjust the time interval.

```
#Last 15 mins
SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM customer_visit WHERE CreateDatetime >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 15 minute) and CreateDatetime <= UTC_TIMESTAMP();

#Between 15 to 30 min
SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM customer_visit WHERE CreateDatetime >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 minute) and CreateDatetime <= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 15 minute);
```

I used [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) but you can use NOW() depending on how you store the datetime in your DB.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which product this is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and some date/time arithmetic.  Something like this:

```
select sum(case when next_cdt < dateadd(minute, 15, CreateDateTime) then 1
                else 0 end) as [<15min],
       sum(case when next_cdt >= dateadd(minute, 15, CreateDateTime) and
                     next_cdt < dateadd(minute, 30, CreateDateTime)
                then 1
                else 0 end) as [15-30min],
       sum(case when next_cdt >= dateadd(minute, 30, CreateDateTime) then 1
                else 0 end) as [<30min]  
from (select t.*,
             lead(CreateDatetime) over (order by CreateDatetime) as next_cdt
      from t
     ) t;
```